# SQL 2008 recursive query for message threads given an entry point of one mesage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, recursive-query

Maybe an over elaborate title.  Basically think of an email inbox.  I have a table 
as so:

[image]

As you can see, it is a recursive table, very simple, just has the parentID of a message, and as you can see with the green highlight ring, the end of the "chain" is when there is a NULL for the parentID.

What I need is to provide (for example) the INBOXID of 12, and return back all parents.. in this example I should get 1 record back which is INBOXID of 11.
In the second example, I should be able to pass in INBOXID of 9, but this time I should get back rows INBOXID 8,7 and 1

I did have some success with the following query:

```
with q as
(
select inboxid, parentid
from bizzbox
union all
select a.inboxid, a.parentid
from bizzbox a
inner join q on q.inboxID = a.parentID
)
select distinct * from q
```

.. but of course it returns all of the parents for any of the rows.. I know it is probably something really stupidly simple like a where clause on one of the selects.. but having tried it (i.e. to parameterize the passing in of the start point inboxid), I can't quite see what I need to do???

Any help much appreciated!!!!!
David.

Comment: Since you're working with hierarchical data, you might consider using the hierarchyid feature: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677193.aspx However, this wouldn't provide a solution for what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Paul, yes I have heard of the hierarchyid feature.. started reading up a bit - and definitely going to be good to select say all siblings of the same tree level etc down the track (for other things).  But right now, the answered question did the trick!  again, many thanks though - all really good info, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
WITH  cte
    AS ( SELECT   InboxID,
                  ParentID
         FROM     BIZZBOX
         WHERE    InboxID = @inboxID
         UNION ALL
         SELECT   prev.InboxID,
                  prev.ParentID
         FROM     BIZZBOX prev
         INNER JOIN cte curr ON prev.InboxID = curr.ParentID ),
     cte1
   AS ( SELECT   InboxID,
                 ParentID
        FROM     BIZZBOX
        WHERE    InboxID = @inboxID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT   prev.InboxID,
                 prev.ParentID
        FROM     BIZZBOX prev
        INNER JOIN cte1 curr ON prev.ParentID = curr.InboxID )
SELECT  * FROM    cte
UNION
SELECT  * FROM    cte1
```

Comment: Wow! genius!  You know I read the SQL statements.. sort of understand what it is doing (obviously quite in need of a SQL course in the new year I think!).. but it is still magic.. and better still, it WORKS!  thank you!!